# Euler characteristic of a topological space and euler characteristic of a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

According to the following Wikipedia article

https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic

the Euler characteristic of a topological space $X$ (with finitely generated homology) is defined as the alternating sum of the Betti's numbers:
$$\chi(X)= \sum_{p}(-1)^p ~ b_p(X)~~~~~~~(1) $$
where $b_p(X)$ is the rank of the torsion-free part of $H_p(X)$.

For a CW complex $X$, the definition of Euler charateristic is defined by
$$\chi(X)= \sum_{n}(-1)^n ~ c_n$$
where $c_n$ is the number of $n$-cells in $X$.

As the Wikipedia article states, these two definitions should be equivalent.
However, Hatcher says at page 146 ([http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)) that, given a CW complex $X$, one has
$$\chi(X)= \sum_{n}(-1)^n ~ H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})= \sum_{n}(-1)^n ~ \text{rank}(H_n(X))~~~~~~~(2)$$
but in general $H_n(X)$ is not torsion free, so I don't understand how are we even allowed to consider $\text{rank}(H_n(X))$ and how (1) and and (2) are related.
What am I missing?

Comment: Rank means the dimension of the torsion-free part.

Comment: Thank you, this makes everything clear.

Comment: @Cirdan_00 Then you should write an answer to your own question.